# Matlab - Working with specific region of interest

Tags: matlab, region

I have an image (see attached) and I am trying to calculate the variance of the image inside the region of interest (dark region) using the stdfilt function.[Image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TVSY.png)
The dark side is what I need to work on. When I use stdfilt on this image, it shows me the boundaries of the dark and bright.

My idea is that we can threshold the image to show only the dark side and tell Matlab to work only with this region of interest. So far, did not find a proper way of doing this.

The area is not a perfect polygon, which would make things way easier. At that point, I'm not sure what to do, so any suggestions are welcome.

Cheers

Comment: What do you want to do with the part that is black? what function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the spatial location of the pixels is not relevant, you could just do:

```
datatoprocess=I(I<threshold);
```

Being threshold a value that separates the white from black. [`graythresh][1]` is a fantastic function for that. `datatoprocess` will be a 1xN array with the pixel values.

If, instead, the spatial location of the pixels is relevant, then you need to modify your functions to not work on specific pixels. The best approach for this is generally setting `NaN` values in pixels you dont want to take into account.

```
Itoprocess=I;
Itoprocess(I>threshold)=NaN;
```

Without more information on what exactly are you doing with the image, this is the best anyone can get to.